# redirect /checkout/cart page

Tags: checkout, cart, onestepcheckout

I've combined my checkout page (OneStepCheckout) and cart page. The /checkout/cart (the cart page) is still accessible, and I wouldn't want my customer to accidentally access that page (reviewing your cart twice would be quite confusing).

Is there anyway I can redirect this page with magento to /checkout ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case you need 301 `redirection` from `checkout/cart` to your checkout page

```
  Mage::app()->getResponse()
        ->setRedirect($someUrl, 301)
        ->sendResponse();
```

use event  `controller_action_predispatch_checkout_cart_index` fire an observer

```
<frontend>
    <events>
        <controller_action_predispatch_checkout_cart_index>
            <observers>
                <customRedir>
                    <class>YourModulePrefix/observer</class>
                    <method>customRedir</method>
                </customRedir>
            </observers>
        </controller_action_predispatch_checkout_cart_index>
        </events>
</frontend>
```

**Observer code:**

```
<?php
class MymoduleNameSpace_ModuleName_Model_Observer{

    public function customRedir($oberver){
          Mage::app()->getResponse()
        ->setRedirect($someUrl, 301)
        ->sendResponse();
        die();

    }
}
```

### Full Module:

As per as your request, i have out full module and as per as customer will `redirect` to `checkout/cart` to contacts us using `301 redirection`.

**config code:**

**location:** `app\code\local\Stackexchange\Magento67150\etc\config.xml`

**code:**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
  <modules>
    <StackExchange_Magento67150>
      <version>0.1.0</version>
    </StackExchange_Magento67150>
  </modules>
  <global>
    <models>
      <magento67150>
        <class>StackExchange_Magento67150_Model</class>
        <resourceModel>magento67150_mysql4</resourceModel>
      </magento67150>
    </models>
    <events>
      <controller_action_predispatch_checkout_cart_index> <!-- identifier of the event we want to catch -->
        <observers>
          <controller_action_predispatch_checkout_cart_index_handler> <!-- identifier of the event handler -->
            <type>model</type> <!-- class method call type; valid are model, object and singleton -->
            <class>magento67150/observer</class> <!-- observers class alias -->
            <method>customRedir</method>  <!-- observer's method to be called -->
             </controller_action_predispatch_checkout_cart_index_handler>
        </observers>
      </controller_action_predispatch_checkout_cart_index>
    </events>
  </global>
</config>
```

**Observer code:**

**location:** `app\code\local\Stackexchange\Magento67150\Model\Observer.php`

**Code:**

```
<?php
class StackExchange_Magento67150_Model_Observer
{

            public function customRedir(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
            {

                $controller = $observer->getControllerAction();
                $controller->getResponse()->setRedirect(Mage::getUrl('contacts'),301)
                ->sendResponse();
                return;
            }

}
```

**Module file: app/etc/modules/StackExchange_Magento67150.xml**

**code is:**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
  <modules>
    <StackExchange_Magento67150>
      <active>true</active>
      <codePool>local</codePool>
      <version>0.1.0</version>
    </StackExchange_Magento67150>
  </modules>
</config>
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, but as a magento 'noob', I must ask: where do I put this code?

Comment: Hey you want to redirect from checkout/cart to your checkout pahe

Comment: Works! Thanks a lot. I had not figured out yet how to create modules. Therefore my first comment. Thanks again!

Comment: One issue though. If I'm at /checkout, and I clear my cart, I will be directed to /checkout/cart, which redirects me to /checkout, which redirects me back to /checkout/cart etcetcetcetc until my browser errors.